# Running into issues with Ubuntu geth >> Error: account unlock with HTTP access is forbidden

Tags: http, ethereum, geth

I am using Ubuntu 18.04-3 and when executing the command >

```
personal.unlockAccount(web3.eth.accounts[0],null)
```

I am getting the following error,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDHIE.png)

I tried some of the suggestions here ([enter link description here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/pull/17037))

and the suggestions [(here)](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/pull/17037) for the `internal/ethapi/api.go`

I included in the  file 
--allow-insecure-unlock  (//I have add as in the suggestions but does not indicate where and how to place it//)

Appreciate your time in advance

Answer (score 1):

You have places `--allow-insecure-unlock` at the wrong place. It should be when starting geth instant.

Example:

```
$ geth {--rpc etc your other flags} --allow-insecure-unlock
```